# Compress HFS+ volume on Linux machine

Tags: linux, mac-osx, filesystems, hfs+

I'm using mkfs.hfsplus to create a HFS+ volume on Linux, but I want to compress it using Apple's UDIF format. It looks like I should be able to use bzip2 to do this, but I can't really tell how.

Any ideas on how I can create a read-only, UDIF compressed HFS+ volume on Linux?

Comment: Looks like this was [cross posted to SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/226426/compress-hfs-volume-on-linux-machine) also...

Comment: But why? What is the larger context?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about UDIF, but HFS+ does support transparent compression. There is an opensource tool called `afsctool` that will be able to convert your files into compressed state. Not sure whether the tool will work on Linux, as I think it uses build-in Mac OS X api.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the source of [FreeDMG](http://www.kelleycomputing.net/freedmg/help/home.html), an OS X utility which can convert DMGs to many different formats. You need to make sure the image type is `UDBZ` (UDIF bzip2 compressed)

You may also want to check out the [dmg2img tool](http://vu1tur.eu.org/tools/), the source here may provide some clues.

Of course your best bet is to use a Darwin / OS X system to do this. Why do you need to use Linux? If you can find a way to do this under Darwin you'll make things a lot easier on yourself.